# Access locking up after first DoCmd.SendOjbect acSendReport

Tags: ms-access

I can click once to launch the following Event Procedure, but if I return to the form to click twice, Access locks up to the point I have to kill the task in TaskManager?

Any advice on this one?

```
Private Sub Command372_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    gTroop = Str(Me.Troop)
    DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "GirlScoutandTroopMatchGlobalVariable", "PDF", Me.TroopLeaderEmailAddress
    MsgBox "Message Sent Successfully."

Cleanup:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 2501
            MsgBox "Email message was Cancelled."
        Case Else
            MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    End Select
    Resume Cleanup
End Sub
```

Comment: `1.` Why don't you use `option explicit`? `2` Why don't you declare a variable and use it and set it to nothing at the end of each sending is completed? It's *loose* enough to lose you...so take care of your variables - clean up!

Comment: Can you be more specific.     Option Explicit was not allowed in a Procedure it tells me. gTroop is a global.  Any other help

Comment: [Invalid inside procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264581%28v=office.15%29.aspx). Do you know how to/where to add `Option Explicit`? Whether a variable is global, public, private, dim..... it must have a type! Don't you think your global is giving you a big time trouble where you have no control over it? [It's `bad` logic design to have global variables....](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad). [Go on and read up](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/40373/so-singletons-are-bad-then-what). FYI: We don't do *spoonfeeding* here

Comment: I had this in my module:    Option Compare Database

Option Explicit


Public gTroop As Integer



Public Function GetTroopValue() As String
   GetTroopValue = gTroop
End Function      I fixed the Click() and lockup by adding to the Cleanup: DoCmd.Close (acDefault)

Comment: Obviously: in my first comment, it says *...take care of your variables - clean up*... If all set then, post it as an answer then! However repeating myself - Globals are legacy bad design....